# How to return value of function out of mainloop?

Tags: python, tkinter

In this code I want to `return` a value out of set `function` but can't.

What should I do?

```
from tkinter import *

temp= 0
def sel():
   selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())
   label.config(text = selection)
   temp=selection
   return temp

root = Tk()
var = IntVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1,
                 command=sel)
R1.pack( anchor = W )
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2,
                 command=sel)
R2.pack( anchor = W )
R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 3", variable=var, value=3,
                 command=sel)
R3.pack( anchor = W)
label = Label(root)
label.pack()
print (sel())
root.mainloop()
```

Why doesn't the `print` function display the result?

Comment: I think you need to read some tutorial first to understand how tkinter works. And please fix grammar errors and typos. This is hard to read.

Comment: Return it to where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `print` function is called before your GUI is running.

If you want to print a message whenever the radio button is selected, you need to add that to the `sel()` function, e.g.

```
def sel():
    selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())
    label.config(text = selection)
    print(selection)
    # temp=selection ## this is unnecessary
    return selection
```

Also your `temp` variable doesn't need to be there, you can use the variable you've already created.

Comment: Thanks , but how can i use result of this function in other function in GuI mainloop?

Comment: Call this function _inside_ another function and optionally assign it to a variable (`a = sel()`).

Comment: Can your other function interrogate the GUI widget to get these details? Otherwise you can assign `selection` to a global variable so it's available.

Comment: @Alireza, it's not clear to me why you want a return from the `sel` function. In your example, the return value seems to be ignored. Can you clarify your intent/desire?

Comment: I want to create several windows which can get information from users and transfer them between each other.